# How to set the $PATH for kitty terminal MacOS?

Tags: macos, path, iterm2, zshrc, kitty

I've been using iTerm2 on my Macbook Pro, but now I`ve just installed Kitty. After writing a few configurations into the Kitty config file, I noticed that, I can't use homebrew (zsh: command not found: brew) but however with iTerm2 I can use it as usual. I recognized that the $path variable is different for the Kitty terminal and the homebrew bin files folder doesn't appear, but if I check the $path with iTerm2, I can see the homebrew path into the $Path. In addition, the aliases I've got defined into the .zshrc file also don't work with Kitty but yes with iTerm2.

So my question is, why do Kitties have a different $path ? and what must I do to Kitty take the correct $path ?

Answer (score 1):

After restart the kitty.config file the problem solved, so I reviewed this config file and the problem seems to be the shell directive, which was set to zsh. I don't know if we have to specify the absolute path to the zsh shell or whatever, but i deleted this directive and then kitty takes the default shell (zsh in my case) and the problem has been solved.